# Create LinkedIn UGC Post with Document Asset

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

The [LinkedIn API documentation for UGC Posts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http) seems to imply you can share a post with a document by setting `shareMediaCategory: "NATIVE_DOCUMENT"`, but there is no additional information about how to make this work. The documentation seems limited to images/videos.

This is what I have tried so far.

```js
const registerUpload = () => {

  // Doesn't seem to be documented, but the API responses on the LinkedIn site
  // returns 'urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-document', so it seemed like a decent guess
  const type = 'document'; // 'image' or 'video' works fine

  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload',
    data: {
      registerUploadRequest: {
        owner,
        recipes: [
          `urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-${type}`,
        ],
        serviceRelationships: [
          {
            identifier: 'urn:li:userGeneratedContent',
            relationshipType: 'OWNER',
          },
        ],
        ...(synchronous ? {
          supportedUploadMechanism: [
            'SYNCHRONOUS_UPLOAD',
          ],
        } : {}),
      },
    },
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenInfo.token}`,
      'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
    },
  });
}
```

which returns the following

```js
{
  serviceErrorCode: 100,
  message: 'Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/registerUploadRequest/recipes/relationshipType]',
  status: 403
}
```

This doesn't make sense to me since `registerUploadRequest/recipes/relationshipType` doesn't match the documented schema. Is there another way to register document assets for UGC posts?

Comment: Did you get around to solving this issue?

Comment: @JoaquimLey No. It didn't seem possible, and we ended up de-prioritizing the feature.